# Функция traceroute из библиотеки icmplib выдает только один последний hop. Не могу отследить путь

Tags: python, icmp

hops содержит только одну запись.
Результат:

> [<Hop 21 [8.8.8.8]>]

```py
from icmplib import traceroute

hops = traceroute("8.8.8.8")
print(hops)
```

Comment: а `print(list(hops))` что выдает?

Comment: вообще, посмотрите на пример работы с traceroute в документации. https://pypi.org/project/icmplib/